# Why Does The NTE5465 SCR In My Circuit Remain Closed, Even With No Current?

Tags: scr

See attached circuit.  Circuit is designed to have the bulb light, when a very low amperage momentary switch is pressed.  In the final circuit, the bulb will draw 4 to 5 amps for a short period of time when current is applied.  Hence the need to protect the low amperage momentary switch.

I am stumped by the actions of the SCR, which after the initial triggering of the circuit, continues to remain closed, anode to cathode, even when no current is applied to the component (I disconnect the D Cell batteries).

I have separately tested the SCR component, and it passes those tests.  Do I just not have this wired in correctly?  Thanks!

Momentary switch when pressed, closes this circuit, which causes the MOSFET to trigger & close.

The Optoisolator Triac.  Pins 4 & 6 remain closed while current is present through Pins 1 & 2.

When current is applied through the gate, this SCR is designed so that the Cathode & Anode close & the bulb lights.  Cathode  & Anode should remain closed until current no longer exists through the Anode & Cathode.

The Problem: Even when current is subsequently disconnected (D Cells removed from the circuit), the bulb immediately re-lights when the power (D Cells) are connected back into the circuit.
In-other-words: the SCR anode & cathode remains close with not current applied to the circuit.

Note: Component passed normal standalone SCR testing methods. A second SCR was even tested & tried in the circuit with the same results...
[image]

Comment: "which causes the MOSFET to trigger & close" - what MOSFET?

Comment: Might be a wiring error. Please post a photo of your setup.

Answer (score 1):

NTE is not really a manufacturer so their datasheets are not necessarily to be fully believed.

If you are getting triggering with a 33K resistor (60uA perhaps) then it would have to be a very sensitive gate SCR however the datasheet shows 15mA maximum (which usually means that 'typical' is not all that much less).

In other words, it **should not work at all**.

Maybe it's wired wrong. If you are sure about the wiring, add a resistor from gate to cathode of perhaps 100 ohms.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71565/discussion-on-answer-by-spehro-pefhany-why-does-the-nte5465-scr-in-my-circuit-re).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that when you re-apply DC you exceed the dv/dt spec for either the opto or the SCR and this causes a trigger to occur. An excessive dv/dt won't naturally damage an SCR or triac but it will trigger it and once triggered it will remain on.

Try testing it with a lab supply where the supply voltage is taken up over a few seconds and see if this happens. You could also try a capacitor (10 nF for example) between cathode and anode of the SCR.

Comment: Thanks Andy aka, I thought about a capacitor.  Sorry I am not clear on "supply voltage is taken up over a few seconds".  Do you mean that I should try with a power supply that is not instant off/on?  What kind of supply would that be?

Comment: @B.Varner a laboratory power supply that has a knob to control the output voltage is what I was thinking of else try using a capacitor as I said in my answer.